# multiply output of string by using custom input

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that would take an ArrayList containing "How", "Are" and "You?" and pass this to a 'stutter' method that will get the output to repeat the words after asking the user for number/how many times they want the word repeated.

Example: if user enters 4, i would pass How, Are and You? and 4 to this stutter method and the output would be How, How, How, How, Are, Are, Are, Are, You?, You?,You?,You?.  This seems simple enough but i cannot get the output correct.  Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Question3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("how");
        list.add("are");
        list.add("you?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many repeats?");
        int repeat = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Before stutter: " + list);
        stutter(list, repeat);
    }
 public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> list, int repeat){
        ArrayList<String> modifiedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String str : list) {
            for(int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
                modifiedList.add(str);
            System.out.print(modifiedList);
        }       
     } 
 }
```

Comment: `System.out.print(modifiedList);` should be outside of both of the loops.

Comment: Can you add the output you are getting to the question?

Comment: @dave If the code was correct, wouldn't he still get the correct answer on the last print? The placement seems to be a debugging technique

Comment: I suppose there is no newlines being printed so the separation between the prints could be deceiving.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier he would, and I think he does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statement is running in the outer loop, so it prints `modifiedList` once for each `str`. Move it to the end of the method so it prints the final result once:

```
 public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> list, int repeat){
    ArrayList<String> modifiedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String str : list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
            modifiedList.add(str);
    }       
    System.out.print(modifiedList);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I feel foolish for having not tried that but it worked like a charm.

Comment: @M.Luke No problem. Please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/304954) if it solved your problem.